# ping using local lookback IP

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ping, ipv4

how can we ping the destination using own lookback IP?

```
eth0      <info>
lo        <info>
lo:0      Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:##.###.###.##  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
```

I want to run following commnad to ping a destination IP (say $$.$$$.$$$.$$)

```
ping -I ##.###.###.## $$.$$$.$$$.$$
```

according to the manual we can use -I (capital I) with the ipv4 address, but I want to implement above command for ipv4 address, what rules should I create for this?

Comment: What device are you running this command on? the local loopback address is 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Lister device : Virtual server RHEL 6.8. yes, lookback (lo) address is 127.0.0.1, but lookback alise (lo:0) is different.

Comment: So you want to ping another device using the loopback? The loopback ip isn't routable, it is used for the device to talk to itself for self diagnostics. You would need to use eth0 with a valid ip to ping an external device. Your question is a bit confusing: The manual states this is how to do it with ipv4, how do I do it with ipv4? with the -I command you should be able to give the name of the alias or the full IP address.

Comment: @Lister yes, I do know the use of lookback ip and I have read the manual as well. and that's what made me to post this question at first. I myself is confused about how to do it, but I think this can be achieved using some rules! (i am not sure)

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble here. What goal are you trying to achieve by doing this? It might help me see what you mean.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want to achieve. You can only send out pings on a specific network interface using an address that's valid for that interface. You can't just add an IP address to the loopback interface, and then use `ping -I this_addr` to spoof a packet sent out to `eth0` (if that's what you want to do).

Comment: @dirkt I gave half a details here, sorry. Actually the lo:0 is a virtual IP of the whole network which I am using for Load balancing. to be exact, lo:0 is VIP and I am trying to ping an outside network server from one of the REAL servers running on RHEL 6.8 (this machine is having a valid eth0 address)

Comment: @Lister please refer to above comment. I am trying to ping a destination (say client) from one of the real servers (current machine) used in IP load balancing using lo:0 ip address (virtual IP of the network).

Comment: @Suraj This should help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it If I say it again I am just repeating myself like a broken record. You cannot, I repeat, cannot, ping an external device using a loopback interface. The loopback is only used to ping itself. the 127.0.0.0/8 network is designated for that purpose only. I'll leave it at that. You have to use a valid interface with a valid ip address.

Comment: Please explain how you intend to use `lo:0` for load balancing, I don't think it will work. Either make a dummy interface with the address (`ip link add dummy0 type dummy`), or add the address to `eth0`. You can only send packets to your own host (localhost) on a loopback device, no matter what you do, so having a second address on `lo` just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Lister yes, you are right. Actually, the tutorial I followed used lo:0 to configure the alise of the current real server, RHEL [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Load_Balancer_Administration/s1-lvs-direct-VSA.html) shows we can use eth0:1 for the same. But the command is still not working! apologies about the immature logic, I am brand-new in networking field!

Comment: @dirkt please have a look at my above comment. It was an honest mistake!

Comment: @Suraj Thats alright, unfortunately I'm not familiar with rhel, I could only help with the loopback part. It may be wise to create a new second question with your new found knowledge, now that you know what your asking for people may be able to better help!

Comment: @Lister have a look at my answer. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @dirkt please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> We can not use lookback IP to communicate with the outside network! **BUT... we can make this command work!**

let's see how..

> What is lookback IP?

The loopback device is a special, virtual network interface that your computer uses to communicate with itself. It is used mainly for diagnostics and troubleshooting, and to connect to servers running on the local machine. [related discription](https://askubuntu.com/a/247626/648984)

> Can we actually use lookback IP to connect with other network machine?

NO! We can't. as @[Lister](https://superuser.com/users/623674/lister) maintained lookback IP is used by the device to talk to itself for self-diagnostics and trouble shooting. Having said that, in the case above to work `ping -I (lookback) (destination)` we can configure the firewall to transfer the requests generated by the lookback IP to be masqurade so as to change the source IP with the valid eth0 IP. **What this means is, we will indeed be using valid IP address of our machine to communicate with destination, but this all will happen under the hood! P.S. destination machine can directly find this out if it try to trace the incoming packets using tshark/ wireshark like tools.**

We can do so using NAT (Network Address Translation) table of the firewall.

- Activate IP-forwarding (mostly disabled by default)

  ```
  echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  ```
- Load Important models for packet forwarding (Usually they are already loaded)

  ```
  modprobe ip_tables
  modprobe ip_conntrack
  modprobe ip_conntrack_irc
  modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
  ```
- Masquerade (change source IP address) the outgoing packets, to source IP as eth0 / eth1

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
  ```

  - t table name
  - A append this rule to postrouting
  - o output to eth0
  - j jump to MASQUERADE
- Test the settings

  ```
  ping -I (lookback_ip) (destination_ip)
  ```

Comment: You can probably use iptables to do all sorts of stuff, but that doesn't mean you should. The loopback interface is for communication with the host itself. Whatever you want to achieve in the end, some other way is better, for portability, maintenance, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would give a full answer to follow up on the comments.

Local loopback uses the ip range 127.0.0.1-127.255.255.254

A loopback device is generally assigned that entire range. If you ping 127.3.3.3 for example your device will ping itself.

When computers talk, they check to see if they are on the same subnet as the device they are talking to. If they are, they will talk, if not, they will attempt to use a gateway (router etc) to try and get there.

Lets assume your network is on the 192.168.0.0 subnet with the subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

If I try and ping 192.168.0.1 from 192.168.0.2 They will look at their subnet and identify their network portion of the ip address (192.168.0) They both see they are on the same subnet, and communicate.

However, if I have 192.168.0.1 ping 192.168.1.1, they will again look at the network portion and see it is different. A message will be sent to the gateway and the devices rely on the gateway to send over the message. If you have no gateway, or the gateway does not know where the network is, then the message is not sent.

127.0.0.1 is always on a different subnet to your network, routing devices will never route traffic from it, and your host machines will not try to send messages from it. If you do send a packet from that ip, it will be ignored by other devices.